# Writing to a text file in c# but when it is displaying in a grid the same information is repeated

Tags: c#, datagridview, foreach, file-writing

So I have created a quiz using c# (just for fun and to learn) 
In my highscore grid the information from the playerdetails class is showing 5 times for the same player instead of once. See code:

```
public frmHighscore()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Only save the test scores once
        if (!File.Exists("highscores.txt"))
        {
            SaveScores();
        }

        LoadScores();
        //Sort the grid based on the value of Column 1 which will be the score value
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Descending);
    }

    private void SaveScores()
    {
        //Open filestram and streamwriter needed to save details to a text file
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("highscores.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

        try
        {
            //loop over each player

            {
                //Write details of the player to the textfile in format playerName~Score
                foreach (Player player in PlayerList)
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(player.playerName + "~" + player.playerScore);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading the scores", "Please try again");
        }
        finally
        {
            //close streamwriter and filestream
            streamWriter.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }

    private void LoadScores()
    {
        //Check if the file exists
        if (File.Exists("highscores.txt"))
        {
            //Read in all the details of the text file
            var playerScores = File.ReadAllLines("highscores.txt");

            //check if players exist in the text file
            if (playerScores.Length > 0)
            {
                //Loop over each player details
                foreach (var playerScore in playerScores)
                {
                    //Add the player name and score to the datagrid
                    var splitDetails = playerScore.Split('~');
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(splitDetails[0], Convert.ToInt32(splitDetails[1]));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Hide the grid and show the No Scores label
                HideGrid();
            }
        }
```

My Player class looks like this:
namespace CWQuiz

```
{
       public class Player
{
    public string Username;
    public int Score;
    public int quizNumber;

    public string playerName { get; set; }
    public  int playerScore { get; set; }

    public static List<Player> player = new List<Player>();


    public Player(string name)
    {
        Username = name;
        Score = 0;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: foreach (var player in PlayerDetails)
   streamWriter.WriteLine(player .playerName + "~" +  player .playerScore);
            }

Comment: what type is `PlayerDetails.playerName` ?

Comment: It is a string type

Answer (score 0):

if the `player` variable is what I assume it is then

```
streamWriter.WriteLine(PlayerDetails.playerName + "~" + PlayerDetails.playerScore);
```

should be

```
streamWriter.WriteLine(player.playerName + "~" + player.playerScore);
```

Comment: according to the comment by OP `PlayerDetails.playerName` is a `string` so `player` would be a `char` and the compiler would complain that it cannot find the property `playerName`.

Answer (score 0):

If as you say `PlayerDetails.playerName` is of type `string`, then you are looping through a `string` which has 6 characters and you print each time the same information:

> `PlayerDetails.playerName + "~" + PlayerDetails.playerScore` => **name~6**.

This is why you get 6 lines.

If you only want to print the name and score of your current player then just use it without the loop:

```
streamWriter.WriteLine(PlayerDetails.playerName + "~" + PlayerDetails.playerScore);
```

If you want to have multiple players in your game
I would suggest to use a proper structure to save the information of the players. Have a class `Player` that contains all your information (which you probably already have)

```
public class Player
{
    public string playerName { get; set; }
    public int playerScore { get; set; }
}
```

and a collection like `List<Player>` that contains all players. You would then loop through the list of players and access the property of each player using the iteration variable `player`.

```
List<Player> PlayerList = new List<Player>();

PlayerList.Add(new Player(){playerName = "Alfred", playerScore = 0});

// start the game
//...

// write down the results of all players
foreach (Player player in PlayerList)
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(player.playerName + "~" + player.playerScore);
}
```

When looping through a collection with foreach then the element `item`

```
foreach (var item in collection)
               ^
               |
```

represents each item and gives you access to its properties. In your case `collection` was a `string` which is composed of `chars` and `item` would represent each character in that string.

**EDIT**

1) The problem is that you added the values into your class:

```
public string playerName { get; set; }
public  int playerScore { get; set; }
```

But you never assign values to them. In the constructor you still initialize only:

```
Username = name;
Score = 0;
```

So you should also use those values. `Username` and `Score` in your for-loop.

2) The next problem is that the `PlayerList` does not belong into the class `Player`. It is not a property of a Player it is a property of a Game so it should be where the game is happening. Because also there you add the players to the list that want to play. Think of it like a real world scenario. In the class `frmHighscore` you want to loop through the `PlayerList`

```
foreach (Player player in PlayerList)
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(player.playerName + "~" + player.playerScore);
}
```

But I don't see any declaration of this variable there. The compiler should complain about this, that it cannot find it. You need to add this there. and also fill it in this class, or pass a reference from the class where you initialize the players and add them to the list.

I hope you understand it better now.

Comment: Ah yes, I ca see now that whatever I put the username as in the for this is the amout of lines I get. However I have ammended the code but see for PlayerList, I do not want to manually add these, it also throws an error saying that it  is a field but is used as a type

Comment: The point of adding a player to the list is just for illustration. As for the error, I cannot help you much since I don't see your code. You can use the [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42552505/edit) below your post to edit, add and update this Information to your question

Comment: @Edel_28 I adopted my answer to your edit. Have a look